# How to set outline border for PNG in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Please see this pic , I don't want second one

which is stupid

[image]

Comment: get your image replaced by designer

Comment: I'm making an app like "meitu", users can add border for their image

Comment: ok, you want to make an app like an image editor. you need to write some code in native android and IOS and then integrate it with flutter. eg: https://github.com/fluttercandies/flutter_image_editor

Answer (score 3):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txov0.png)

```html
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


///ImageEdgeTest
///담당자 : ---

class ImageEdgeTest extends StatefulWidget {
  const ImageEdgeTest({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ImageEdgeTest> createState() => _ImageEdgeTestState();
}

class _ImageEdgeTestState extends State<ImageEdgeTest> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("ImageEdgeTest")),
      body:Column(
        children: [
          Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
                ImageFiltered(
                  imageFilter: ImageFilter.dilate(radiusX: 5,radiusY: 5),
                  child: Image.asset('assets/object/img_tree.png',color: Colors.red,),
                ),
              Image.asset('assets/object/img_tree.png'),
            ],
          ),
          Image.asset('assets/object/img_tree.png'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If the border thickness is not too big, it is possible to use the **simple_shadow** package: https://pub.dev/packages/simple_shadow

A simple example:

```
import 'package:simple_shadow/simple_shadow.dart';

SimpleShadow(
    color: Colors.red,
    opacity: 1,
    sigma: 5,
    offset: const Offset(0, 0),
    child: Image.asset(imgBird),
  );
```

PNG: [Bird.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9Vor.png)

Result: [Bird with SimpleShadow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jvwx.png)